# How to add files from multiple locations to one Zip file in Ant

Tags: ant

I would like to know how i can include files from multiple locations in one zip file in Ant task.

I am able to use `<zip>` to generate from single folder using `basedir`

I don't know how I could give multiple locations

```
ex locations: C:\Temp\D1
              C:\Work\DataSets\ 
              ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this (more in the [docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)):

```
<zip destfile="${dist}/example.zip">
  <zipfileset dir="C:/Temp/D1" />
  <zipfileset dir="C:/Work/DataSets" />
</zip>
```